# Issue converting Sitecore Item[] using ToList<T>

Tags: c#, sitecore, generic-list

Working with Sitecore and Linq extensions.

I am trying to convert to from an item array to the list using the following piece of code:

```
Item variationsFolder = masterDB.SelectSingleItem(VariationsFolderID.ToString());
List<Item> variationList = variationsFolder.GetChildren().ToList<Item>();
```

However I keep getting this error whenever I try to build:

```
'Sitecore.Collections.ChildList' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments
```

I have the following usings:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Am referencing:

```
System.Core
```

I've just copied this code from another location, so it should work fine, can only think that there is something simple (like a reference or something that I am missing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any experience with SiteCore, but does `ChildList` implement `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` perhaps?

If so, try this:

```
List<Item> variationList = variationsFolder.GetChildren()
                                           .Cast<Item>()
                                           .ToList();
```

Basically `Cast<T>` converts an `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>` by casting each element.

Comment: Notice that this is fixed in version 6.2.
Then you can use ToList() right away.